# JSTL access HttpSession attribute size

Tags: list, jsp, jstl

I have a list of items stored in my HttpSession. Is it possible in my jsp page to access the size of this list directly? (**Without using scriplets**)

What I am doing currently is this...

```
var count = 0;

<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.myList}" var="temp">
                count++;
</c:forEach>
```

This works, but is there a nice clean way to access the list size, without looping through the list?

Comment: Yes this works, this is a snippet from a javascript method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSTL [`fn:length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html) function.

```html
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
There are ${fn:length(sessionScope)} attributes in the session scope.
```